# How To Test The Apk File Before Publishing Google Play Store?

Tags: android

How To Test Apk File Before Publishing It Google Play Store. Because I've Already My Old Account Terminated By Multiple Violations.

Please Help Me How To Test Apk File Before It Publishing To Check Is There Publishing Or Not Or Have Already Publishing Same Styles.

Is There Tell Me By Video Tutorial Because I'm New.

Comment: You can test through USB debugging..!!! There are many online android testing websites are available(Keynote,testdroid, ubertester etc). Please check it

Comment: I'm closing this as off-topic because there is no information here as to what problems your APK file was failed for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the APK from Android Studio and from Genymotion. If there's a publishing error, maybe there's a lack of information on your signing form from the Android Studio.
Also, check the Android Manifest, and if there's something missing or another error, delete the APK or the Manifest and start over.